# How to clean a file path?

Tags: python, micropython

Is there a cleaner, shorter, perhaps more elegant or Pythonic way to do this?

**Unique constraint:**  The same code has to work on both Python 3.x and MicroPython.  This means that a lot of the nice tools available in Python 3.x cannot be used.  Hence the "back to basics" feel to the code.

It attempts to clean-up some malformed input.  That's not super important.  Also, yes, it has to behave on both Windows and Linux.  I tested on Windows and MicroPython on an RP2040 processor (RaspberryPi Pico).  Works fine.

**Warning:** If you run this code on your system it will create over twenty directories.  Make sure you run it on a junk directory.

```
import os

def create_path(path:str) -> str:
    """Given a path with a file name, create any missing directories

    Does NOT create files.

    :param path: "some/subdirectory/file.txt"
    :return: The new full path, ready to open the file
    """
    result = os.getcwd()

    # Cleaning up an leading and multiple slashes
    while "//" in path:
        path = path.replace("//", "/")

    if len(path) > 0:
        path = path if path[0] != "/" else path[1:]

    elements = path.split("/")
    for element in elements:
        if element == "":
            break
        else:
            result += "/" + element
            if "." in element:
                break  # It's a file; we are done
            else:
                # It's a directory, does it exist?
                try:
                    os.listdir(result)
                except:
                    # It does not, create it
                    os.mkdir(result)

    # This is necessary to remove a leading double slash
    # when used in MicroPython
    return result.replace("//", "/")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Tests
    # WARNING: This will create over twenty directories!
    # Does not create the file, just the path
    print(create_path("/"))
    print(create_path("//"))
    print(create_path("///"))
    print(create_path("file_01.txt"))
    print(create_path("/file_02.txt"))
    print(create_path("//file_03.txt"))
    print(create_path("///file_04.txt"))
    print(create_path("dir_00"))
    print(create_path("/dir_01"))
    print(create_path("//dir_02"))
    print(create_path("dir_03/"))
    print(create_path("dir_04//"))
    print(create_path("dir_05///"))
    print(create_path("/dir_06"))
    print(create_path("/dir_07/"))
    print(create_path("//dir_08/"))
    print(create_path("//dir_09//"))
    print(create_path("dir_10/file_05.txt"))
    print(create_path("/dir_11/file_06.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_12/file_07.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_13//file_08.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_14//file_09.txt/"))
    print(create_path("//dir_15//file_10.txt//"))
    print(create_path("dir_16/dir_116/file_11.txt"))
    print(create_path("/dir_17/dir_117/file_12.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_18/dir_118/file_13.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_19///dir_119/file_14.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_20///dir_120///file_15.txt"))
    print(create_path("//dir_21//dir_121//file_16.txt/"))
    print(create_path("//dir_22//dir_122//file_17.txt/"))
```

Comment: Don't know about Windows but on Unix type systems, multiple adjacent forward slashes are considered as one

Comment: You can try using `os.stat` over `os.listdir`. Also since you already replaced the double slashes early on in the while loop, I don't think the replacement in the return statement is necessary.

Comment: I love to use this to make code clean: '\\' if os.name=='nt' else '/'

Comment: @OluwafemiSule "I don't think the replacement in the return statement is necessary."  If you are running this on Linux or MicroPython os.getcwd() returns "/" when at the root directory.  This causes a double slash on output if you append anything at all to the path with this code.  I could redo the code to not insert slashes between elements and, perhaps, join everything in one step at the end.  In other words, just take care of creating directories that are not there and then build a path string.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule "not available APIs in micropython".  Right.  That's precisely the problem.  There are better ways to do this in full Python.  MicroPython imposes some limitations.  Since I am trying to make this compatible on both (it's part of a larger library), this makes things a bit complicated.

Comment: @Robinmaltaros MicroPython does not have os.name.  It has os.uname(), which returns a tuple with a bunch of information.  os.name will result in an exception.  I guess that's one way to identify the os...until that changes.  Technically MicroPython isn't an operating system, however, at least in use on an embedded system, it ends up becoming one.